# How do I update column's values from another column?

Tags: go-gorm

In short, I'm trying to do the following using the [gorm package](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm).

```
UPDATE TableName t SET t.col1 = t.col2;
```

Is there a way to do where gorm only does 1 query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using Gorm methods

```golang
db.Table("TableName t").Update("t.col1", gorm.Expr("t.col2"))
```

Source: https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/issues/1947#issuecomment-397376537